# sh not found on shell

Tags: linux, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am facing with a `while` loop executing inside shell.
Below is the script and error :

```bash
while [ $(curl -s http://<servicename>:<portnumber>/hazelcast/health | jq '.clusterSize') -ne $(size_1) ];do 
  sleep 2
  echo 'Waiting for the `bjy-hazelcast'
done
```

Output :

`sh: 3: not found`

Comment: Can you share more about your shell script. one line is not enough

Comment: hi @ souhail 
while [ $(curl -s http://<servicename>:<portnumber>/hazelcast/health | jq '.clusterSize') -ne $(size_1) ];do sleep 2;echo 'Waiting for the `bjy-hazelcast';done"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Assuming size_1 is a command, if not change `"$(size_1)"` to `"$size_1"`

```
while [ "$(curl -s http://<servicename>:<portnumber>/hazelcast/health | jq '.clusterSize')" -ne "$(size_1)" ]
    do 
        sleep 2
        echo 'Waiting for the `bjy-hazelcast'
    done
```

Comment: Hi @souhail
after trying the above solution i do receive either out of range or below message 

/app/services/spring-webservices # "$(curl -s http://hazelcast-service.bjy:8711/hazelcast/health | jq '.clusterSize')"
sh: 3: not found

Answer (score 0):

`$(...)` is a process substitution, and the text inside is interpreted as a command.  It would seem that `$size_1` is expanding to the string `3`, and the shell is attempting to execute `3` as a command and complaining that it cannot find such a command.  You should omit the `$()` and just do:

```
"$(curl ...)" -ne "$size_1"
```